# Is there any chance FOF become the default way of do things in Joomla?

Tags: component, development, mvc, fof

Joomla has several MVC classes (model, view, controllers, table etc).
Now we have the FOF classes in library that can be used instead the default joomla classes in our components, but I don't see them being used in core components. Is there any chance FOF replaces the default MVC classes in the future?

Here is the [FOF Developer's Guide](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/fof.html)

Comment: Move to F0F (Zero instead of O) and keep using it, as the future of it has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, FOF is used for the postinstall messages and for the two factor authentication.

Unfortunately the developer of FOF retracted his offer and is no longer contributing FOF to Joomla core.
Thus using it as default is out of question and we in fact have to refactor the existing uses of it.

Comment: so, FOF is going away from joomla? The custom components that use it is going to break?

Comment: I'm hoping the core will leave the last version in place until 4.0 so that third party extensions don't break, in theory by time 4.0 is released everyone should have enough time to update so they install [FOF](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/fof.html) if required.

Comment: I just saw the discussion about the developer of FOF retracted his offer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/frameworkonframework/VxxIKvTooXU)

Comment: FOF will likely be deprecated and removed with Joomla 4.0.

Comment: Note that FOF will keep going as a standalone thing so everyone can keep using it. Also the Joomla core will also start to provide a more automated approach to doing things hopefully in the future

Comment: F0F is the just-released fork of FOF. https://github.com/akeeba/fof

Custom components can work on the current FOF v2.2.1, distributed in Joomla v3. 

If there's any need of fixes or new features, custom components should work with F0F (renaming FOF* calls to F0F).